# Eclipse keyboard language

Tags: android, eclipse, keyboard, character

I am using a English (U.S.) Windows XP laptop that has Eclipse (Helios-SR1) installed. I created an Android app that runs fine on the emulator and my Samsung Charge phone. However, I have one app screen that requests the user's name and email address. The input form is located on my website and I use the WebView function (and INTERNET permission) to capture the input data and store in a MySQL database table. The problem I am experiencing is that each character that I input (either using the Eclipse keyboard or laptop keyboard) is changed to an Oriental character (I think its Chinese). I don't understand why the input characters are changed.. WTF! I've been researching for the past 2 days and can't find a solution to make the input characters English (U.S.). I would appreciate any help in resolving this problem. Thanks ahead of time.

Regards,
Terry

Answer (score 0):

change the input language in the emulator and disable the Japanse and Chines keyboard as if it were a real phone.

In android 1.6

- go to Settings -> Locale & Text -> select locale
- select English (US)
- go to Settings -> Locale & Text
- unselect the *first option* which has some Chinese (I think) characters and *Japanese IME*

Comment: Hi Augusto.. Thanks for your response. However, I do not understand. I do not see any items in the Eclipse tool bar that points to Settings or Locale & Text. What application contains the Settings or Locale & Text functions? I looked at the settings in Windows XP (Regional and Language Options) and I have English (U.S.) selected. Please let me know if I'm missing something? Regards.. Terry

Comment: I guess I was slow coming out of the gate. I was finally able to figure it out. First, activate the Eclipse program and then click on the menu button (bottom of screen). Next, click on Settings -> Language & keyboard -> Uncheck the Chinese characters line item -> Check the Android keyboard line item. Done! Thanks for the help.